# Interpretable models apart from Logistic Regression

Tags: machine-learning, logistic-regression, machine-learning-model, model-selection

I am wondering about other interpretable models apart from logistic regression.

I am looking for models that can interpret the effect on the target variable by unit change in any feature variable.

I was thinking tree-based models may help but I'm not sure.